# Is there a generic mime-type for all image files?

Tags: mime-types, image-processing

I know that I can use the specific mime-types as listed for example [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/), or a generic mime-type for any file like `application/octet-stream`, but is there a generic mime-type for all image files?

(I want to edit a `.desktop` file in Linux Mint KDE to create an 'Action' context-menu entry in Dolphin File Manager that would be shown only for image files.)

Comment: Would `image/*` work (like browsers do)?

Comment: @Boldewyn - `image/*`works for the purpose indicated in my question, even for `svg` files - that is, as a Desktop entry like `MimeType=image/*`.  Please answer [this more specific question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232525/32012) to which you comment is the answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Is there a generic mime-type for all image files?

Normally there isn't, but there are a couple of exceptions documented later in this answer.

You need a Mime Type in order to know how to process a file (without having to read the file header).

Notes:

- Not all image files have a header that identifies their type.
- [SVG files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), for example, are just XML files. So without the correct mimetype or extension there would be no way to correctly identify the type of the file.
- Mime Types are specified as Content-Type/subtype
- There isn't a Mime Type `image/generic` (See "Further reading" below for the full list of IANA registered image subtypes).

---

#### Does it mean that there is a mime-type for multiple image files?

There is no **single** `Content-Type/subtype` that covers multiple image formats.

In theory you could use an unknown Subtype such as `image/xyz` but W3C says explicitely:

"a Content-Type of `image/xyz` is enough to tell a user agent that the data is an image, even if the user agent has no knowledge of the specific image format `xyz` ... "such an action might be reasonable for unrecognized subtypes of text, **but not for unrecognized subtypes of image or audio**"

> In general, the top-level Content-Type is used to declare the general type of data, while the subtype specifies a specific format for that type of data.
>
> Thus, a Content-Type of "image/xyz" is enough to tell a user agent that the data is an image, even if the user agent has no knowledge of the specific image format "xyz".
>
> Such information can be used, for example, to decide whether or not to show a user the raw data from an unrecognized subtype -- such an action might be reasonable for unrecognized subtypes of text, but not for unrecognized subtypes of image or audio.
>
> For this reason, registered subtypes of audio, image, text, and video, should not contain embedded information that is really of a different type. Such compound types should be represented using the "multipart" or "application" types.

Source [W3C - The Content-Type Header Field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

---

#### Can I use a wildcard like `image/*` for my special case?

> so that it can be used for my purpose without the need of specifying the singular file extensions/mimes?

Yes. As you have pointed out a wildcard can be used when specifying the "Desktop Entry" for the the KDE and GNOME desktop environments.

However, please note that Key=`MimeType` is deprecated as there is a new standard for this.

> `Type=MimeType` is deprecated as there is a new standard for this now, see the [Shared MIME-info Database specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/Standards/shared-mime-info-spec) for more information. In consequence the Keys Patterns (various file name extensions associated with the MIME type) and DefaultApp (the default application associated with this MIME type) are also deprecated.

Source [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)

You can also use wildcards for mime types in IIS, but is advised to **not** do this:

> You can also configure IIS to serve undefined file types by adding a wildcard character (*) MIME type.
>
> Do not use wildcard MIME-types on production servers. Doing so can result in IIS serving unrecognized files and displaying sensitive information to users.
>
> Wildcard MIME-types are intended for testing purposes or in scenarios where Internet Server API (ISAPI) filters have been developed specifically to handle these wildcard scenarios, for example, a custom authentication ISAPI.

Source [Creating Global MIME Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737070%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

---

#### Further reading

- [IANA - Registered Media Types - Image](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) (Image Content-Type and subtypes)
- [W3C - The Content-Type Header Field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

Comment: Does it mean that there is a mime-type for **multiple** image files - not all, but many, so that it can be used for my purpose without the need of specifying the singular file extensions/mimes?

Comment: @cipricus There is no **single** `content-type/subtype` that covers muliple image formats.

Comment: @cipricus Answer updated to address your comment.

Comment: as indicated in a comment under my question, `image/*`works for the purpose indicated in my question, even for `svg` files - that is, as a Desktop entry like `MimeType=image/*`.

Comment: It may well work, but according to [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) -  "`Type=MimeType` is deprecated as there is a new standard for this now, see the Shared MIME-info Database specification for more information. In consequence the Keys Patterns (various file name extensions associated with the MIME type) and DefaultApp (the default application associated with this MIME type) are also deprecated."

Comment: Thank you foe you well-documented answer. As a practical solution for my limited purpose (create an 'Action' context-menu entry in Dolphin File Manager that would be shown only for image files), `image/*` works. In its present form your answer is the most adequate, but I don't get a positive solution out of it. I have asked [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232525/32012) a more specific question.

Comment: I will update the answer to include your solution for the limited case.

Comment: Hang on... Which type do we use for images then? Or did I miss the point

Comment: image/* works for web browsers' file chooser

Answer (score 2):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779690/is-there-a-generic-image-mime-type-that-modern-browsers-recognize), there is no generic MIME-Type. The problem is that the MIME-Type is always composed of a Type, a Subtype and an optional Parameter: `Type/Subtype; Parameter` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)). You only want to use the type, but by definition a subtype is required and there is no generic subtype. A list of all image types can be found [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image).

Comment: Oddly, that list of "all" image types has blanks for `gif` and `jpeg`, whereas this list https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/ shows that they are `image/gif` and `image/jpeg` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

according to adobe you may use any of this

[image]

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/assets/administer/assets-formats.html?lang=en#supported-mime-types
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/assets/dynamic/config-dms7.html?lang=en